# SCP in Java with URIs without password and username

Tags: java, linux, ssh, scp

How do I SCP a file from a RHEL linux box to another RHEL linux box without the password and without the username using URIs in Java using [SCPClient](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/doc/api/com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/ssh/SCPClient.html)? I know how to do a passwordless ssh, and I can SCP a file without the password, but I'm having trouble getting it to work without the username.

Here's my guess:

Source: file:///home/username/temp.txt

Destination: scp://@192.168.1.1:/home/username/

Comment: i can imagine very few valid scenarios that don't require a password (or key) for SSH/SCP...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `scp://username@192.168.1.1:/home/username/` ?

Comment: I know that works. The problem is that I don't know the "username" when I want to SCP.

Comment: Then you cannot SSH/SCP. SSH/SCP cannot determine the use by the public key alone.

Comment: @Everlight Username is mandatory... SCP is over SSH... you are logging into the remote box.

Comment: There's no way to simply attempt to login as one of the listed available users? Or rather, to use the username that you are scp-ing from without telling SCPClient what the username is? like, how I can do "ssh -Y 192.168.1.1"? - which uses the current username and passwordless ssh.

Comment: Ah, that gets you the current username - use `System.getProperty("user.name")` to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the [SCPClient](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/doc/api/com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/ssh/SCPClient.html#setAuthentication(java.lang.String,%20com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ssh.SSHAuthPrompt[])) page I'm going to say that it's not possible. So, the best method is to do

```
SCPClient scpc = new SCPClient
scpc.setRemoteHost( "192.168.1.1" );
scpc.getValidator().setHostValidationEnabled( false );
scpc.setAuthentication( "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa", System.getProperty("user.name"), "" );
scpc.connect();
scpc.put( "file:///home/username/temp.txt", "scp://" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "@192.168.1.1:/home/username/" );
```

For my purpose its safe to assume the remote username is the same as the local username.